# Can't add third party reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I try to add a reference in my asp.net core project. But when I want to add that dll (its a third party dll) error is shown (below). How can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: As a workaround can't you create a local NuGet package and then reference it?

Answer (score 1):

It is known issue, please take a look at https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1672